# How to pass special character as parameter in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to parametrize the Column Delimiter field in CSV dataset in Azure Data Factory.
[image: img1]

This unfortunately doesn't work when I pass a special character as a parameter.

When I hardcode the special character in the column delimiter field all works as expected.

[image: This works]

However, when I have \u0006 as a parameter in SQL DB (varchar(10) type)
[image: img]

and I pass it in the pipeline
[image: img]

The Copy Data activity doesn't detect this special character as a delimiter.

My guess is that when I use a parameter it passes \u0006 as a string, but I can't find anywhere how to bypass that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to pass `\u0006` in column delimiter as a dynamic content. It didn't consider that as column delimiter. All data are shown as a single column.
[image]

Therefore, I tried to pass equivalent symbol of \u0006 `ACK`() as a dynamic value to that column delimiter and it worked. I tried to convert the \u0006 into the special character using SQL script. Below are the steps to do this.

- File delimiters are stored in a table.[image]
- To convert this column into equivalent characters, \u is removed from the column and the resultant hexadecimal value is converted into an integer. Then nchar() function is used to the integer data.

`select nchar(cast(right(file_delimiter,4) as int)) as file_delimiter from t5`

- The above SQL query is used in Lookup activity in ADF.

[image]

- When this value is passed as a dynamic content to column delimiter to that dataset, values are properly delimited.
- Once pipeline is run, data is copied successfully.
  [image]